# Why the latest updates removes pycrypto-2.0.1

Tags: python

When I reinstall the latest unity-control-center it removes pycrypto-2.0.1. I then install manually and replace pycypto library with the latest one pycrypto-2.6.1? But when I try to add IDEA Crypto.Cipher (which is removed in latest releases of pycrypto) but without success.
Is there any solution for adding IDEA crypto.cipher and mdc2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like pycrypto is a dependency of [unity-control-center](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+source/unity-control-center) 
so I do not think that this is what caused the package to be upgraded. Instead, I think that you had installed an older version of this package and when apt saw that there was a newer version available it installed if for you.

This is the nature of the apt package manager. If you wish to stay on a specific version of a package then I would suggest that you pin it. You can learn more about [how to pin a package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) here.

Comment: Thank you levlaz, it seem really that it was replaced after some update, but i didn't mention when it was done.

Answer (score 0):

After 6 year I get some experience, and find a solution of my problem in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I compile the latest version of Openssl (which is 1.1.1k)
Fetch the tarball: wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz
Unpack the tarball with
tar -zxf openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz && cd openssl-1.1.1k

Before compilation, I enter into downloaded folder (in my case it is

> ~/src/openssl/
> and
> tar xvf

openssl source configuration folder

```
simple variant of configuring
```

./config enable-mdc2 enable-idea -DMDC2_ASM -DIDEA_ASM enable-md2 enable-rc5 -DMD2_ASM -DRC5_ASM
then do the common things for compilation
$make
$make test
to check for possible errors.
$sudo make install

Then I wait for the OpenSSL compile process. Go to the '/etc/ld.so.conf.d' directory and create new configuration file 'openssl-1.1.1k.conf'.

```
cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ && sudo vim openssl-1.1.1k.conf

sudo ldconfig -v
```

Run the command
sudo ldconfig
to update symlinks and rebuild the library cache.
Again, from the terminal issue the command:

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021

and I have finally Crypto.Cipher in python installed